# How can I make my android emulator faster?

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

I'm using the Andyroid emulator and it seems whenever I try to play an app/game then it becomes incredibly slow and laggy to the point that I can't even play said game. Are there any settings I can tweak to make it faster?

I have around 4 GB of RAM and my processor is AMD Athlon 64 X2 Dual Core 4800+ 2.50 GHz.

Comment: i think GenyMotion is better option.

Comment: You have maybe run your Android Emulator in ARM achitetecture, run it on x86 it will be faster cause your computer don't have to translate

Comment: @Aniruddh Parihar But, that isn't free right?

Comment: its free... you have to just signup only.

Comment: Lol, nevermind. I bought a new PC a few months ago (i5-7400, GTX 1050 Ti) and now it's not lagging anymore. I guess my PC just needed a good upgrade. :)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly update to the latest Android Studio. Emulators start work faster and faster with new Android Studio versions. Also make sure you select x86 image, during emulator setup. Arm emulators are very slow.